# How to retrieve the child added to a MovieClip?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a .fla file that consist of several timelines, and movieclips are added and removed constantly.

I need to programatically get some info from those added and removed movieclips, the problem is, I can't capture it, I have this:

```
private function swfLoadedHandler(e:Event):void {

        var mc:MovieClip = e.currentTarget.content;
        mc.addEventListener(Event.ADDED, onAdded);

}
```

And then I got this in the event handler:

```
private function onAdded(e:Event):void {

   trace(e.target.name);


}
```

All of the children are exported for actionscript movieclips and have instance names. If I loop through them manually, I can find them, but the event wont.

The target in that example instead of beign my recently added movieclip is a "Shape" and the name is something like isntanceNN.

Any ideas what could be wrong?.

Comment: Could explain more your question ? Which kind of information do you need to get ? And `swfLoadedHandler()` is the handler of which event exactly ? ...

Answer (score -1):

Eventhough it's not the best idea, you could use `.name` property;

```
private function swfLoadedHandler(e:Event):void {
    var mc:MovieClip = e.currentTarget.content;
    mc.name = "myMc";
    mc.addEventListener(Event.ADDED, onAdded);
}

private function onAdded(e:Event):void {
   trace(e.target.name); //myMc
}
```

If still nothing, check that if you have nested movieclips are you receiving the instance names of the inner objects.

Comment: I doubt you understood the question.

Comment: Might be. How about the inner objects?

Comment: That is exactly what I'm not receiving, and I wonder why is that.

Answer (score -1):

you should either use ADDED_TO_STAGE event, 
`mc.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);`
because this event doesn't bubble. And your currently caught `ADDED` event will trigger your listener for all the inner objects in the `mc`. Or you should trace your `currentTarget` instead of `target`. But better use both:

```
private function swfLoadedHandler(e:Event):void {
    var mc:MovieClip = e.currentTarget.content;
    mc.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);
}

private function onAdded(e:Event):void {
   trace(e.currentTarget.name);
}
```

this should probably help

**update:** ok. if you need to get objects that are added **directly** to your movieclip, so you probably should check their parent?

```
private function swfLoadedHandler(e:Event):void {
    var mc:MovieClip = e.currentTarget.content;
    mc.addEventListener(Event.ADDED, onAdded);
}

private function onAdded(e:Event):void {
   const myMc:DisplayObject = e.currentTarget as DisplayObject;
   const addedObject:MovieClip = e.target as MovieClip;

   if (addedObject && (addedObject.parent == myMc)) {
       trace(addedObject.name);
   } else {
       trace(addedObject.name + ", [not interested!]");
   }
}
```

Comment: That code is the same as kaarto. I will repeat myself, my main movieclip is a swf class that I load in runtime, the children are the ones I need to get the values of.

Comment: Why are you declaring as const myMc and addedObject?. Anyway, the code is flawed. addedObject will always exist, it is the target, it can't not exist. Also "directly" doesn't make any sense, since the ADDED event bubble, it could be a child of a child.

Comment: well, if the target is not MovieClip, then `e.target as MovieClip == null` , it is the rule of type conversion with `as` . Directly does make a sense, because i check if `myMc` is the exact parent of the addedObject. so if it had been added deeper, it won't pass the check.

Comment: also, what does it mean 'flawed' ? Since i don't have your loaded movieclip, i can't even predict, what's happening. I guess you have to post some trace results or something.

Comment: and one more variant for you: since you know all the names you're interested in, just keep the array of these, and heck them on added. `if (interestingNames.indexOf(e.target.name) > -1) { trace("YAY! Found " + e.target.name); }`

Comment: if you read the original question, that is what I do, I check the movieclips once they are added, but the name of the movieclips does not return what I want.

Comment: @Artemix But if you didn't set a `name` to your added MC, you will always get `isntanceNN` !!! May be you mean the class name ?! I don't really know what do you want to do !

Comment: Again, please guys, read my question. I did set a name to each added movieclip.

Comment: @Artemix Sorry, but it's not to us to understand your unclear question but it's to you to clarify it ! We try just to help you not to guess what's the question ! Try to clarify your question with all needed details and examples, and what you are doing exactly ! You are speaking about setting names but I didn't see how/where did you do that !? ...

Comment: The names are set inside the .fla file, in the instance name textbox. When I loop through the children, I can get the movieclip.name, however when a new child is added the event object doesn't return the name property, but an "instanceNN" name.

Comment: @Artemix OK, you can get the name because you'v already set it in the instance name text box, but for the new added child (I don't know from where, the library may be !), how / where / when did you set the name ?!

Comment: how: in the properties panel inside Flash Pro. where: inside the fla when: before I load it

Comment: You dont have instance text box for the new children of movieclips you add, use the name property and name them. New child is always an instance. It may contain some prenamed objects, but itself it is instanceNN.